# Assertion Failed in MapBase.h file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, eigen, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying to use the Eigen code (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8-64 bit platform, but I am getting the error related to "Assertion Failed" in `MapBase.h` file.

```
...........
eigen_assert(EIGEN_IMPLIES(internal::traits<Derived>::Flags&AlignedBit,(size_t(m_data) % 16) == 0) && "data is not aligned"); 
..............
```

[image: Assertion Failed Error Screen Shot]]

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Post *your* code. Preferably, a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As the assert tells you, the data m_data isn't aligned to a correct 32/64bit boundary. The project is configured to check the alignment of pointers.

Check the call stack, probably you used a wrong pointer (i.e. -1) for such an object, or you have a heap corruption, or you overwrote memory.